# How to filter store in combobox of editorgrid based on record's value?

Tags: extjs, combobox, grid, extjs3

I have one grid in which there is one column for combobox. I require to filter out combobox's value based on the record like below :

```
 id  |   name    |      options
======================================
1    |  string   |  combobox(1,2,3)
2    |  string   |  combobox(1,2,3,4,5)
3    |  string   |  combobox(1,2,3)
1    |  string   |  combobox(1,2,3)
```

So ultimately I require the value of options based on `id` column. Following is my extjs grid column config.

```
columns: [{
                header: 'id',
                dataIndex: 'id',
                id: 'id',
                hidden: true
            },{
                header: 'Name',
                dataIndex: 'name',
                id: 'name',
                menuDisabled: true,
                flex : 1 
            },{
                header: 'options',
                dataIndex: 'options',
                id: 'options',
                menuDisabled: true,
                flex : 1,
                editor : {
                    xtype : 'combo',
                    store: optionStore,
                    valueField: 'id',
                    displayField: 'name',
                    triggerAction: 'all',
                    mode : 'local',
                    disabled: true,
                    listners: {
                        expand: this.filterFunc(this)
                    }
               },
               renderer: this.columnRenderer
            }]
```

How can I filter store without for different row in ExtJS editorgrid.

P.S - I'm using extjs 3.4 version

Answer (score 1):

You can use the renderer, it should go something like this:

```
renderer: function( value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store ) {
    value.store.filter( [
        {
            property: 'filteredProperty',
            value: record.get('id')
        }
    ] );
}
```

Comment: Thanks it, but it didn't work for me because I'm using special renderer for displaying values in dropdown.

Comment: How does that renderer look? Wouldn't it be possible to use that renderer to filter the properties?

Comment: No @MarthyM, it's little complicated to alter renderer. Though your solution works perfectly, still I'm posting my way of solving problem.

Answer (score 1):

I used below column config with listeners `expand` which filter the store while expanding list of combobox.

```
{
    header: 'options',
    dataIndex: 'options',
    id: 'options',
    menuDisabled: true,
    flex : 1,
    editor : {
        xtype : 'combo',
        store: optionStore,
        valueField: 'id',
        displayField: 'name',
        triggerAction: 'all',
        mode : 'local',
        disabled: true,
        listeners: {
            expand : function(combo){
                var id = Ext.getCmp('grid').getSelectionModel().selection.record.data.id;
                combo.store.filter('attributeId',attributeId);
            }
        }
   },
   renderer: this.columnRenderer
}
```

Comment: Great solution. I would personaly use `afterrender` listener, though. If you use `expand`, it could show a default value, that was not in your filtered list, before you expand it.

Comment: Thanks for your concern but no such value exist as I already put constraints in database. :)